# date comparison in JPQL

Tags: java, dart, jpql

I have a comparison of two dates in my application code. The code is in Flutter, but is easy, so you can understand it even if you don´t know Dart:

```
selectedDayCalendar.isAfter(item.canceledDate.add(Duration(days: 15)))
```

Here I want to know when the date selected in Calendar is after other date + 15 days. The problem is:
data can only be shown when date 1 is before or on the same day as date 2 (+ 15 days). If I do this validation in the application, the API will still bring data that I will not use, so I wanted to do this validation in the API itself. The API can only bring in data where:

```
!selectedDayCalendar.isAfter(item.canceledDate.add(Duration(days: 15)))
```

How I can do this validation in JPQL Query SELECT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED:

I put Instant.now() in a local variable, then I created another one with instant.now() + 15 days. I passed these two variables by parameter to the function JPQL Query.

it was like this:

```
        Instant startDate = Instant.now();
        Instant endDate = startDate.plus(15, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

        return eventService.findByTrainerLoginCanceledDateBetween(startDate, endDate);
```

and JPQL:

```
@Query(
        "SELECT e " +
        "FROM Event e " +
        "WHERE e.status = '' OR e.canceledDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate"
    )
    List<Event> findEventByLoginAndCanceledDateBetween(Instant startDate, Instant endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

JPQL doesn't support adding days to a date sadly, so you'll have to use a native query:

```
SELECT e FROM Item e WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 15, e.canceledDate) < CURRENT_DATE
```

I think something like that.

But some people don't like the mix of using native and JPQL queries combined.

Comment: Very nice your resolution, thank you so much. I talked to my team and we thought there is a way to solve it without adding days to the date in jpql. I will create a date variable in the application, add 15 days and pass it in the GET parameter. 
To display only the ones that are between one date and another, I'm going to use BETWEEN in the JPQL Query.

Comment: That's also good, very nice thinking